# Which files should be imported in a subversion repository for a web services project?

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, svn, apache-axis

I created a Java Project in Eclipse using the Web services Top down approach (i.e. creating a WSDL file and using it to generate the Skeleton Java class and web services with axis2) (Hence, there are a lot of auto-generated files and axis2 jar libraries).

My Project has the following files/directory structure:

```
- Deployment Descriptor         
- build              
- build.xml                 
- doc (i.e. generated javadoc)         
- src     
  - com.package1
  - com.package2
  - Libraries
    - Apache Tomcat 6.0 (apache jar files)
    - Web App libraries (axis2 jar files)
- lib (containing external jar files)          
- resources     
- WebContent           
  - axis2-web           
  - META-INF    
    - MANIFEST.MF    
  - WEB-INF 
    - classes
    - conf
    - lib
    - modules
    - services
    web.xml
- wsdl (contains WSDL file)
```

I want to import this project into a subversion repository on a remote host. Which files should be imported in order to ensure anybody checking out this project can have it up and running quickly? As per my understanding, we DO NOT import jars, class files, into subversion repository. What should be the best approach here? I am especially unsure of all the web app axis2 and tomcat libraries, and directories like axis2-web, META-INF, WEB-INF (in WebContent).

Answer (score 3):

- If possible use [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) or [Ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/) - these will handle the dependency management, so you don't need to commit jars
- don't commit auto-generated files
- avoid committing IDE resource files (but you can be less strict with this)

Comment: +1 for avoid committing generated files because if somebody decides to customize 1 file.... god help you/him/everybody in the project, then!

Comment: There are cases where you *should* commit auto-generated files; e.g. when using EMF ...

Comment: @StephenC - yes, that's why I was not so strict on that point - sometimes it's 'allowed' :)

Comment: What about the part of the question "I am especially unsure of all the web app axis2 and tomcat libraries, and directories like axis2-web, META-INF, WEB-INF (in WebContent)."